# Set global replacement macros

Tags: markup

There are ways to set global style. But how about add user define code?

If the use of the following summation notation is expected to appear for countless times:

```
\sum_{i=1}^n \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty}
```

Is there any way to user-define this string into a certain code at the very beginning of the document such as "SUM" and later on when I type something like:

```
$SUM$
```

I can get the result analogous to

```
$\sum_{i=1}^n \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty}$
```

And when I type:

```
$\displaystyle SUM a_i(x_ty_t)+SUM b_i(y_t)^2$
```

I will have:

```
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty} a_i(x_ty_t)+\sum_{i=1}^n \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty} b_i(y_t)^2$
```

Comment: Well, not `SUM` but `\newcommand{\MYSUM}{\sum_{i=1}^n \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty}` will do with `\MYSUM`. That's the purpose of macro definitions ;-) ... `\to` is perhaps better than `\rightarrow`

Comment: why using `\displaystyle` in inline math?`

Comment: to make the "limits" position at the top and bottom of the summation

Comment: @Howard, this would increase the height of your text line

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is there any package required for "\newcommand{\MYSUM}{\sum_{i=1}^n \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty}"? I  get an error " File ended while scanning use of \@argdef." when adding it before \begin{document}.

Comment: @Howard: Sorry, I forgot a `}` in my comment above. See my answer

Comment: if you want limits on the sum you should use `\sum\limits` (as you have for `\int`), `\displaystyle` changes the _whole formula_ but the whole point of  _inline_ math is to use a compressed style that fits in the line spacing of a paragraph and that defeats it, better to use a display `\[\sum....\]` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is meant. More features require a command with arguments etc.

The `\displaystyle` isn't recommended for inline math, since it increases the text height of the line, see the `Inline:` text.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\MYSUM}{\sum_{i=1}^n \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow -\infty}}

\begin{document}
$\MYSUM$

Inline: $\displaystyle \MYSUM a_i(x_ty_t)+\MYSUM b_i(y_t)^2$

Inline: $\MYSUM a_i(x_ty_t)+\MYSUM b_i(y_t)^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]